# How to logout a user from the login page?

Tags: javascript, express, passport.js

```
function checkLogged(req, res, next) {
    for(i = 0; i < logged.length; i++) { 
      if(req.user.id == logged[i].id) { 
        if(logged[i].sid != req.sessionID) {
            req.logOut()
            return false
        } 
      } 
    }
    return next() 
}
```

The function checks whether there are users who are logged in, if there are users who are logged in, they will be entered into the array. And if another user enters with the same name, it will be removed.

**"One session per user"**

The above functions are going well. Now I want to ask, what should be done so that users do not enter pages ('/') and logout (sessionIDs are also deleted) from pages ('/') and back to ('/ login') pages. I tried req.logOut, but it can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make a redirect

```
function checkLogged(req, res, next) {
    for(i = 0; i < logged.length; i++) { 
      if(req.user.id == logged[i].id) { 
        if(logged[i].sid != req.sessionID) {
            req.logOut();
            return res.redirect('/login');
        } 
      } 
    }
    return next() 
}
```